# Abaqus BoundingBox for nodes

Tags: abaqus

I have made a simple plate in Abaqus/CAE, with dimensions [x, y, z] of [0.1, 0.004, 0.1].
For my project, I need to use the same plate over and over, but with different mesh sizes, and thus different amount of nodes.
I need to find stress values on the edge of the plate, for every plate. I wanted to do this using the getByBoundingBox feature. My code is as follows, I've also included the error message:

```
>>> allNodes=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['PLT 100x100x4'].nodes
>>> allNodes.getByBoundingBox(0.04, 0.001, 0.09, 0.06, 0.003, 0.11)
()
>>> mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['PLT 100x100x4'].Set(name='PLTmiddleNodes', region='PLTmiddleNodes')
TypeError: region; found string, expecting Region
>>>
```

The standard getByBoundingBox code is:

```
getByBoundingBox(xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax)
```

I think I did everything right, as my box now encloses just a section of the edge of the plate. However, suspicions arose when line 2 returned '()'. Next to that, I got a TypeError.
Could somebody help me with this?

PS: I am relatively new to Abaqus, and coding as a whole. Please forgive me if I've missed something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is problem in arguments of `getByBoundingBox` box. You need include all nodes within the bounding box ( will not work if it is on boundary of bounding box). Choose the arguments according to that. You can try these command in Command Line Interface. 
Secondly, You need to store the nodes into a `variable`. And then you need to pass to create the node set.

```
# Get all nodes container
allNodes=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['PLT 100x100x4'].nodes

# get a subset of nodes using getByBoundingBox
PLTmiddleNodes = allNodes.getByBoundingBox(0.04, 0.001, 0.09, 0.06, 0.003, 0.11)

# create the node set
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['PLT 100x100x4'].Set(name='PLTmiddleNodes', region=PLTmiddleNodes)
```